# Alias for column name on a SELECT * join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, alias

I have two tables -  client and person. They are linked by `personID` in both tables.

I am trying to create a view.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM client INNER JOIN person ON client.personID = person.personID
```

It didn't like it saying `Duplicate column name 'personID`.

I thought if you used `table.column` that was fine as an identifier. I tried with and without single quotes.

I could do an alias if I wanted specific columns EG `client.personID AS perID` but I cannot work out how to make an alias for the columns in this position IE when they are part of the JOIN definition.

I have been looking and trying for over an hour and just cannot find it.

**EDIT:** This is a question SPECIFICALLY about aliasing columns in a SELECT * join. Everyone seems to be saying put in the explicit columns. I know how to do that. I deliberately want to use a * JOIN for development work. This will be a tiny DB so it does even not matter if it stays in. Oh and **this is only a problem storing as a VIEW not as an SQL query or in a bit of code**.

Comment: expand the `*` into properly aliased fields

Comment: ^^ `SELECT *` is fine for quick prototyping, but it's not a good practice to use it in production, especially in a `JOIN` query or view for exactly the reason you've discovered. Be explicit about listing all the columns and aliasing where needed so your view's columns are predictably ordered.

Comment: Thanks guys but the defining the columns is exactly what I am trying to avoid. If I do that then I have to SELECT about 14 columns and will have to update this as the structure of the DB evolves which is exactly what I am trying to avoid. Is there no way (using '(' or '{' or whatever) to do the aliasing away from the column selection? Also why can the SQL not parse the `table.column` format in this part of a query? Seems v odd.

Comment: why wouldn't you list the columns? How much effort is that really? If you alter the table then add the new needed columns. but how often are you going to alter the table design?

Comment: Long story can we just assume I want to and it will be useful to me. Sorry that might have sounded snarky - wasn't meant to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have to alias you'r column names with aliases.

```
SELECT client.column1 as col1, client.column2 as col2, person.column1 as colp1 FROM client INNER JOIN person ON client.personID = person.personID
```

Of course, replace the column names into the real column names as use more appealing aliases

Let us know if it helps

### UPDATE #1

I tried creating 2 tables with sqlfiddle in mySQL 5.5 and 5.6

see link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e70ab/1

It works as expected.

Maybe you could share you tables schema.

Here's the example code :

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
personID int,
  name varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Client
(
ID int,
  name varchar(255),
personID int
);

insert into Person values(1, 'person1');
insert into Person values(2, 'person2');
insert into Person values(3, 'person3');

insert into Client values(1, 'client1', 1);
insert into Client values(2, 'client2', 1);
insert into Client values(3, 'client1', 1);

SELECT * FROM client 
INNER JOIN person 
ON client.personID = person.personID;
```

Comment: Sorry my comment should have gone up under the original question

Comment: Please show the result of selecting both tables or give us the names of the column.  ill run a try on my local mySQL

Comment: Did you store that as a VIEW? This is the mystery. It works fine for me as a normal SQL query or in a bit of code it is just in the VIEW it will not work.

Comment: According to my researches, when creating a view, the column names are stored and mySQL will complains with the error #1060.

See : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49173

You have no choice but to list the columns with aliases.

Comment: My conclusion too but pretty poor show. You can use `table.column` everywhere else EXCEPT for storing `VIEW`s which seems like a bug to me. (IE it "should" work but the coding does accept what is part of the syntax everywhere else). Ah well I will not be bothering with the `VIEW` just using the statement every time I need it....

Comment: I totally agree with you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100202/discussion-between-wmehanna-and-oldmauiman).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
        c.*,
        p.`all`,
        p.need,
        p.`fields`,
        p.`of`,
        p.person,
        p.`table`,
        p.without,
        p.personID_field
    FROM client c
    INNER JOIN person p
        ON p.personID = c.personID
```

Answer (score 1):

#### What is the problem

In SQL, top-level `SELECT` statements are allowed to produce the same column name twice. Any form of nested `SELECT`, derived table, or view must produce unique column names. This is why joining two tables and simply selecting all the columns from the tables can produce issues in a view.

Often, people will resort to prefixing all columns in views via well-established prefix naming conventions, e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW v_client_person AS
SELECT
  client.clientID AS clie_clientID,
  client.name     AS clie_name,
  client.personID AS clie_personID,
  person.personID AS pers_personID,
  person.name     AS pers_name
FROM ...
```

This is a good idea because you will be easily able to disambiguate any column from such a view.

#### A workaround

If `personID` is the *only* conflicting column between your two tables, then you could use `JOIN .. USING` as a workaround:

```
CREATE VIEW v_client_person AS
SELECT * FROM client INNER JOIN person USING (personID)
```

`USING` has the nice effect in most databases, including MySQL, to produce the join column only once in the resulting records, independently of what table it originated.

#### A note on `SELECT *` in general

In general, however, you shouldn't use `SELECT *` in a view, but explicitly list and name all your columns as [suggested by wmehanna](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34688984/521799) or in my previous note. There are several reasons why you should omit `SELECT *`:

- In top-level selects: [Performance](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-08/its-not-about-the-star-stupid) (this might not be such a problem in nested selects, if the top level select doesn't select all the columns of the nested select)
- In views (including derived tables): Your view definition depends on the storage order of columns, as well as their names. When the table column changes, your view definition is stale and the behaviour is somewhat undefined. It's generally a good idea to keep in control of your query output, which is why `SELECT *` is not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: ... and suggested by many others. I am not sure I see the real harm in SELECT *. There might be a small overhead but I suspect mySQL is fairly well optimized for SELECT *. I am enjoying playing with `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` which is a hoot! I am working on a personal project that is unlikely to have 1,000 records total, I cannot believe that the SELECT * will be much of a problem but using a stored VIEW and FETCH CLASS means lots of flexibility and lots of lovely code that does not need editing. I can hear code purists grinding their teeth but my code is my code.

Comment: Sorry what I forgot to say was thanks a million for the USING idea. Will see tomorrow if mySQL allows it in VIEWS. Slightly surprised that no one has really addressed the question of WHY unambiguous, legal code is NOT allowed in a VIEW. Most odd (the "bug" @wmehanna pointed to was from 2009 so it seems no one cares) - ah well. Many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: @OldMauiMan: My criticism here isn't about performance of `SELECT *` but the fact that you don't know in what order columns will appear, and what they're called. It's better to stay in control of these things and select them explicitly, in views. I'll extend my answer to explain things a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying all the column names that you want to show instead of using * with listing the column names along with table names that are common to both tables like don't say personID, type client.personID